# Screens flicker when calling glViewport after window style was changed

Tags: windows, opengl, fullscreen, flicker, windowed

In my OpenGL application I switch between windowed and fullscreen mode using
Raymond Chen's solution:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/12/9994016.aspx

This works apart from two very annoying side effects when used in a
multi-monitor setup (only):

1. After the window mode was switched BOTH screens flicker/flash just in the
   moment glViewport is called to accommodate the changed window dimensions.
2. Windows on the desktop from other applications are not painted correctly
   after the switch until I e.g. minimize/maximize them (or do something similar
   to force a refresh).

Does one know these effects and maybe also knows a solution?

ps: further tests showed that this only happens on my PC with an AMD card but not with my Nvidia card. If only one monitor is active it doesn't happen at all.

Comment: Which version of Windows do you use?

Comment: @datenwolf: I use Win7 64bit

Comment: What happens if you disable Aero?

Comment: @datenwolf: I haven't enabled Aero... My settings is 'classic' which doesn't even offer composition.

Comment: This sounds like a driver issue then (especially the windows not being redrawn issue). There's not really a lot you could do.

Comment: @datenwolf: I updated the driver and point 2 (incorrectly painted windows) is solved now. (Weird I didn't think about updating as I always try that first... #-o) Unfortunately point 1 still persists but I'll keep it on my radar and I will post a solution if I'll ever find one.